# Reference Error loading Stripe Elements API

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement the basic test code of Stripe Elements Docs but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried changing the order of the scripts but doesn't work either.
The error I get is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: elements is not defined

```
<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
var style = {
base: {
  // Add your base input styles here. For example:
  fontSize: '16px',
  color: "#32325d",
}
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to create an instance of stripe and then the instance of elements

Refer to [Stripe Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference)

Comment: Now I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: (my public key) is not defined plus the same error before.

Comment: Have you signed up with them and got a key?

Comment: If you receive an error which says (your public key) is undefined, then it means tou are using it as a variable instead of string..